# Angular 1 to Angular 5 (import nested components)

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular5

Before

- Angular 1.5
- ui-router

Now

- Angular 5.0

How import subcomponents in a component father like a angular 1.5?
I do the tutorial Heroes from angular 5, but not explaint this transition, all components are imported in app.modole.ts.

The next image try to explain a litle how a I have imports in angular 1.5

[image]

**Someone know how import subcomponents in a component in the new angular 5? 
or is absolute necesary import all components in `app.module.ts`?**

Comment: I don't totally understand your question, but all components must be declared in a module. The module could be `app.module.ts`, it could be another module (though if module B declares a component, and you wish to use that component in module A, module B must export that component and module A must import module B)

Comment: Please don't use "Solved" in your title.  Mark an answer as "accepted", or if none have directly solved your problem, answer your own question and mark it as "accepted".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is no different to AngularJS in any way. This can be done with single App module (which isn't enough for complex applications), or a hierarchy of modules.

In AngularJS:

```
angular.module('app', ['foo'])
.component('app', {...});

angular.module('foo', [])
.component('foo', {...})
.component('barUsedByFoo', {...});
```

In Angular:

```
@NgModule({ declarations: [FooComponent, BarUsedByFooComponent], exports: [FooComponent] })
class FooModule {}

@NgModule({ imports: [FooModule], declarations: [AppComponent], bootstrap: [AppComponent] })
class AppModule {}
```

Angular team proposes the concept of [feature modules](https://angular.io/guide/feature-modules). Feature module should explicitly specify its dependency on other modules with `imports`. All module components are specified in `declarations` and (optionally) `exports`.

The difference from AngularJS is that Angular modules are allowed to have local components. If `BarComponent` with `bar` selector is specified in both `declarations` and `exports`, it will be available in all component templates. If `BarComponent` is specified only in `declarations` and not `exports`, it will be available only in component templates from this module. This way different modules can have different `<bar>` that won't pollute global namespace.

If `BarComponent` is route component, it should be specified in both `declarations` and `exports`, because this way it will be available to router module.

Answer (score 1):

Components are included in a module. So a module contains and encapsulates 1 or more components and "expose" them to public with `exports` keyword. You inject all the services in the module so all components and subcomponents will have the same instance - singleton service.

After you create the components that you want and declare them in the module then you can use them in the html template as siblings, children component etc. it won't matter.

So as an example if you have a `<users>` component which will be the statefull parent component, inside that template you can add any component child you will need for example `<user-personal-details>` `<user-acedemic-details>` etc. The only thing you need to do is import all these in the same module.

Edit: I guess this part of the docs https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3 could help you more to understand. If you read what that CLI command does is `... (HeroDetailComponent) declares the component in AppModule.` And then in the `heroes.component.html` it adds it just like this `<app-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></app-hero-detail>`