# How do I make an Angular directive usable only by one component?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive, angular-components

The only way I know of being able to use my directive is by exporting it in the module.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [BreadcrumbsComponent, IsRightDirective],
  exports: [BreadcrumbsComponent, IsRightDirective]
})
export class BreadcrumbsModule { }
```

My BreadcrumbsModule is imported by my AppModule

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BreadcrumbsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now when I use my breadcrumbs component, which I named the selector `bulma-breadcrumbs`, and add the attribute, `is-right`, it works as expected. However if I add it to another tag, like an `h1`, the directive also affects it.

I'm trying to get the directive to only apply on the `BreadcrumbsComponent`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before Angular 2 RC5, a hierarchy of directives/components was transparent, because components had `directives` property that defined components/directives that affected only this component and its children.

After the introduction of `NgModule`, this feature remained intact but became less evident. As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48845024/3731501), it's possible with proper hierarchy of modules.

Most times module `declarations` and `exports` are same, this allows to use module directives, components and pipes globally within the application.

If a unit isn't exported from a module, it's available only locally, to other units within same module.

This

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [BreadcrumbsComponent, IsRightDirective],
  exports: [BreadcrumbsComponent]
})
export class BreadcrumbsModule { }
```

will prevent `is-right` attribute directive from being compiled anywhere but this module declarations (i.e. `BreadcrumbsComponent`).

Alternatively, directive `selector` can be restricted to `bulma-breadcrumbs[is-right]`. The result will be same, but this won't prevent the directive from being used in other modules that have their local `bulma-breadcrumbs` component.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description, I was going about this all wrong. I didn't understand that the export was for use in other templates. Good to know. I also like how I can have the selector just be for the element. Exactly what I'm looking for. Every bulma-breadcrumbs element with is-right. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can make the directive effective only if the element `tagName` is `bulma-breadcrumbs`:

```
export class IsRightDirective {

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    let element = elementRef.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    if (element.tagName.toLowerCase() === "bulma-breadcrumbs") {
      element.style.border = "solid 4px red";
      ...
    }
  }

}
```

See **[this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-driven-form-2-aa1few)** for a working example of the code.